# Maui How to disable a button when using Command-binding

Tags: maui, commandbinding

I am using a **command binding for a button in Maui**. The button's *IsEnabled* property does not work because of the command binding. Even if *IsEnable* is set to true, the command is not fired.  **How can I disable the button in the ViewModel class at the constructor in *new Command(..)* so that the command does not fire and the button looks disabled?** (Like toggling from one to the other button.)

On [learn.microsoft..](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/data-binding/commanding?view=net-maui-7.0) I read:

> Warning
>
> Do not use the IsEnabled property of Button if you're using the command interface.

XAML:

```
<ScrollView Style="{StaticResource mainScrollView}">
    <VerticalStackLayout>

        <HorizontalStackLayout>
            <Button Text="Month" 
                    Command="{Binding SetMonatCommand}"
                    Style="{StaticResource buttonCalendar}"
                    IsEnabled="{Binding IsListActive}"/> <!-- IsEnabled IS NOT WORKING -->
            <Button Text="List" 
                    Command="{Binding SetListeCommand}"
                    Style="{StaticResource buttonCalendar}"
                    IsEnabled="{Binding IsMonthActive}"/> <!-- IsEnabled IS NOT WORKING -->
        </HorizontalStackLayout> ...
```

ViewModel:

```
public partial class CalendarPageViewModel : ObservableObject, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
private readonly CalendarService _calendarService;

[ObservableProperty]
private bool _isMonthActive;

[ObservableProperty]
private bool _IsListActive;

public ICommand SetMonthCommand { get; set; }

public ICommand SetListCommand { get; set; }

public CalendarPageViewModel(CalendarService calendarService)
{
    _calendarService = calendarService;

    SetMonthCommand = new Command(() =>
    {
        IsMonthActive = true;
        IsListActive = !IsMonthActive;
    }); // is not called when using IsEnabled at the XAML

    SetListCommand = new Command(() =>
    {
        IsListActive = true;
        IsMonthActive = !IsListActive;
    }); // is not called when using IsEnabled at the XAML
} ....
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the `CanExecute()` method, so that the button will be set to `IsEnabled=false` based on the boolean property in your ViewModel. This way you only need one boolean whether the month or list is shown, also do not forget to call `NotifyCanExecuteChanged()` on your command, so that it re-evaluates the `CanExecute()` method. You can also use the handy `RelayCommand` attribute from the CommunityToolkit.Mvvm nuget package.

```
        [ObservableProperty]
        private bool _IsListActive = true;

        [RelayCommand(CanExecute = nameof(CanSetMonth))]
        private void SetMonth()
        {
            IsListActive = false;
            SetMonthCommand.NotifyCanExecuteChanged();
            SetListCommand.NotifyCanExecuteChanged();
        }

        private bool CanSetMonth()
        {
            return IsListActive;
        }

        [RelayCommand(CanExecute = nameof(CanSetList))]
        private void SetList()
        {
            IsListActive = true;
            SetMonthCommand.NotifyCanExecuteChanged();
            SetListCommand.NotifyCanExecuteChanged();
        }

        private bool CanSetList()
        {
            return !IsListActive;
        }
```

To make the button look disabled, you could use the `VisualStateManager`, which should be already in styles.xaml when you create a new MAUI project.

```
    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Primary}, Dark={StaticResource White}}" />
        <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
            <VisualStateGroupList>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray950}, Dark={StaticResource Gray200}}" />
                            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray200}, Dark={StaticResource Gray600}}" />
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateGroupList>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

The xaml code:

```
        <Button Text="Set Month" Command="{Binding SetMonthCommand}" />
        <Button Text="Set List" Command="{Binding SetListCommand}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If a button has the `Command` attribute, it’s `IsEnabled` attribute is disregarded, and the button remains enabled. However, if you bind the `Command` attribute, then the state of the `IsEnabled` attribute depends on the `CanExecute` state of your `Command`. Rather than binding `IsEnabled` directly, it's better to include the necessary logic in the `CanExecute` state of your command.

```
public ICommand SetMonthCommand { get; set; }

public CalendarPageViewModel(CalendarService calendarService)
{
    SetMonthCommand = new Command(ExecuteSetMonthCommand, CanExecuteSetMonthCommand);
}

private void ExecuteSetMonthCommand()
{
    IsMonthActive = true;
    IsListActive = !IsMonthActive;
}

private bool CanExecuteSetMonthCommand()
{
    return IsMonthActive;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, when you declared the variable such as `private bool _isMonthActive` without setting it value. It will used the bool's default value(false). It mean the button will be disabled as first and the command can't be executed.

In addition, I have create a new project to test your code and found that the command will not execute even though I set the `isMonthActive` and `_IsListActive` as true. So I used the RelayCommand instead of the ICommand. Such as:

```
 public partial class CalendarPageViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
       

        [ObservableProperty]
        private bool _isMonthActive ;

        [ObservableProperty]
        private bool _IsListActive ;


        public CalendarPageViewModel(CalendarService calendarService)
        {
             IsMonthActive = true;
             IsListActive = true;
        }
        [RelayCommand]
        public void Test1()
        {
            IsMonthActive = false;
            IsListActive = !IsMonthActive;
        }
        [RelayCommand]
        public void Test2()
        {
            IsListActive = false;
            IsMonthActive = !IsListActive;
        }
       
    }
```

And use it in the xaml:

```
 <Button Text="Month"
                    Command="{Binding Test1Command}"    
                    IsEnabled="{Binding IsListActive}"/>
 
        <Button Text="List"
                    Command="{Binding Test2Command}"
                    IsEnabled="{Binding IsMonthActive}"/>
        </Button>
```

The command will execute. **Note:** **the button's command is disabled when the button's IsEnabled property is false. So if you want to excute the command, you need to set the button's IsEnabled property as true.**